# How do I unit test a 32 bit SSIS package on a 64 bit machine?

Tags: unit-testing, ssis, 64-bit

I've got to create an SSIS package to move some data around. I can write an SSIS package on my 64 bit development machine but SSIS only runs on 32 bit machines. It's simple enough that I can make something that looks like it should work and hand it over to QA, but I'd like to write unit tests for it or even do TTD on this. Is there some way I can do that or do I have to skip unit tests for this?

Comment: +1 Good question.  I might try using stored procedures and build unit tests around them, but it's hard to know without having some idea of what the package is doing and what your development environment is.  It is possible to write tests for SSIS, but I haven't done that in a mixed environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your package in 32 bit mode (on a x64 machine) from the command line using dtexec.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /f "C:\MyPackage.dtsx"
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to integrate that call into your testing framework.